# WebDriverError: Could not start Browser / Emulator error

Tags: protractor

Oflate , I have been observing below error when ran my protractor tests on browserstack.

"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: Could not start Browser / Emulator"

Here is my protractor config file.

```
 let browserstack = _.defaults({
 user: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME,
 key: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY
 }, {
 user: '**',
 key: '**'
 });

let timeoutMultiplier = 2;
 exports.makeDefaultCapabilities = function(that) {
 return {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
  prefs: {
    credentials_enable_service: false,
  },
  loggingPrefs: {
  driver: 'WARNING',
  server: 'WARNING',
  browser: 'INFO'
  },
  'browserstack.user': browserstack.user,
 'browserstack.key': browserstack.key,
 'browserstack.debug': true,
 build: that.params.BUILD_NUMBER || '(unknown)',
 maxInstances: 2,
name: that.baseUrl,
}
};

 exports.config = {

 suites: {
  e2e: [
  '*/*.spec.js'
 ]
 },

SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
baseUrl: undefined,
framework: 'jasmine',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 60 * 1000 * timeoutMultiplier,
realtimeFailure: true
 },
maxSessions: 1,
params: {
BUILD_NUMBER: undefined,
CI: undefined,
TIMEOUT_MULTIPLIER: timeoutMultiplier
},
 seleniumAddress: 'https://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub',
 useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,

 getMultiCapabilities: function() {
 return new Promise(function(resolve) {

  let capabilities = [];
  capabilities.push({
    os: 'OS X',
    os_version: 'High Sierra'
  });
  resolve(capabilities);
});
},

onPrepare: function() {
browser.manage().window().maximize();
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
let reporter = new SpecReporter();
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
}
};
```

Test that is failing :

calling function :

```
 async clickButton() {
 await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
 await waitForEl(this.Button);
 await browser.sleep(10000);
 await this.Button.click();
 await browser.sleep(10000);
 await this.stopButton.click();
 await waitForElAbsence(this.Bar);
 await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
 }
```

used above calling function in below spec:

```
 it('should check if button is clicable', async function() {
  let po = new check({
    url
  });
  await po.go();
  await po.clickButton();
  });
```

Has any one experienced it before ? Also the error is seen only browserstack and not on my local computer. Also the test i pasted is not the only one failing . Tests are failing randomly with this error.

I have protractor v5.3.2

Comment: From the capabilities block, I am assuming you see the behaviour on desktop chrome. Any error you see on the browserstack dashboard for these cases?

Comment: Yes, I see "BROWSER START-UP FAILURE" error.